# I am having issues while installing MongoDB compass on my mac locally

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am having issues while installing MongoDB compass on my mac locally. How to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Did you install and start MongoDB?